# Expanding a divergence term

Tags: vectors, divergence-operator

I am trying to prove the following as a part of a larger derivation:

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}-N\gamma^{wn}(\nabla^\sigma.N)$$

Where,

$N$ is the unit vector normal to the interface

$\gamma^{wn}$ is a scalar

surface divergence operator, $\nabla^\sigma=\nabla-NN.\nabla$

projected surficial identity tensor, $I^\sigma=I-NN$

Here is my attempt:

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=\gamma^{wn}\nabla^\sigma.I^\sigma+I^\sigma.\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}$$

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=(I-NN).\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}+\gamma^{wn}\nabla^\sigma.(I-NN)$$

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=I.\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}-NN.\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}+\gamma^{wn}(\nabla^\sigma.I-\nabla^\sigma.NN)$$

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}-(N.\nabla\gamma^{wn})N-\gamma^{wn}\nabla^\sigma.NN$$

$$\nabla^\sigma.(\gamma^{wn}I^\sigma)=\nabla^\sigma\gamma^{wn}-(N.\nabla\gamma^{wn})N-\gamma^{wn}(\nabla.N)N-\gamma^{wn}(N.\nabla{N})$$

So terms 1 and 3 are what I needed, but I got two more terms. I am not sure if I did this correctly and what I have missed.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can and should type out the equations here using standard LaTeX (MathJax), instead of using an image. If you typed the stuff in your image out in LaTeX, you could probably just copy-paste the LaTeX code here with minimal changes.

Comment: See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)